# Spring Security Meta Annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-security

Is it possible to build Meta Annotations of Spring Security `@PreAuthorize` like for `@Component` or `@Qualifier`?

What I want to do is replace `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")` by a shortcut like `@IsAdmin`. But I did not find any hint in the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works at least with Spring Security 3.0.2.RELEASE:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
public @interface IsAdmin
{
}
```

Comment: I have tested it several times, but it does not work. The problem seams to be, hat the new annotation `IsAdmin` does not trigger an Aspect pointcut.

Comment: Unfortunately, I no longer have the project I tested this with (it was at a former employer), and don't remember the specifics, as I no longer work with web-software/Spring Security. Could it be a configuration issue? Some version difference? Did you try to place it in the interface (I seem to recall that at least with some Spring Security annotation, the only way it would work was placing it the interface, not in the implementation class).

Comment: I use real AspectJ as weaving mechanism (because I have no Interfaces). May there is a difference between AspectJ and Spring AOP. But in general I believe it is not possible to have an Pointcut based on Annotation Meta Definition, because I dont know of an point cut definition that supports Annotation Meta Definition.

Comment: That could be it, if my memory serves, we were using proxies and not weaving.

Comment: I will test this (sorry that this will take some time) and if it is aspectJ vs. Proxy Problem, I will give you a hint and ask you to add this note to you answer, and then accept it again. -- If this is ok for you.

Comment: No problem and take your time, I'll update the answer to include your findings.

Comment: Works with Spring 5.

Comment: Meta annotations stopped working in my project after migrating it to Spring Boot. Seams like a bug in the framework

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's documented in the official documentation (Spring Security 5.1) : see [Method Security Meta Annotations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.x/reference/html/authorization.html#method-security-meta-annotations)

Example provided :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize("#contact.name == authentication.name")
public @interface ContactPermission {}
```

Answer (score 1):

esajs example is correct:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
public @interface IsAdmin
{
}
```

however for some strange undocumented reason this will not work in my Spring Boot (vr 2.1.2.RELEASE) project without the `proxyTargetClass` option turned on in configuration like so:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
    prePostEnabled = true,
    proxyTargetClass = true
)
```