# create new spring annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I'm developing an application in Spring which has numerous methods in the controller, and are mapped to various URL using @RequestMapping.

Some of these methods (and hence url) are accessible to some user roles, and not to others. Can I create annotations, and annotate these methods so that only privileged users have access to right methods, while not to the others?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if creating new annotations is what you really need. You could probably use Spring Security and its annotations. Please take a look [here](http://www.jroller.com/habuma/entry/method_level_security_in_spring) to see if it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spring Security and its annotations, restrict access to some methods. This [Blog post](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/06/03/spring-security-300m1-released/) show some features of annotations used with Spring Security 3.

Have a look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402723/spring-security-meta-annotation), to see how you build your own annotations on top of spring security.

See also the documentation of [Spring Security 3.1, Chapter Expression-Based Access Control](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#el-access).