# Authorizing methods in Spring MVC Controller

Tags: java, authentication, spring-mvc, spring-security, annotations

My aim is to protect some methods in my Spring 2.5 MVC Controller only to be accessed by specific users for e.g for Managers can access all the methods but Viewers can access a few of them. Though I have to access the session object to know if the current logged in user is a manager or not. I have a method for that.

```
 public boolean isManager(HttpSession session){

//Dome some check
}
```

The controller method I want to protect will look like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getInfo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getInfo(ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {

      //do something

        return new ModelAndView("info_page", model);
    }
```

So in the above method I want to have annotation which will allow only Managers to access that method.

For e.g I want to have something like this

```
@RolesAllowed(AcessType.ManagerOnly)   
@RequestMapping(value = "/getInfo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getInfo(ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {

      //do something

        return new ModelAndView("info_page", model);
    }
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528844/create-new-spring-annotation)question but it didn't help me how to pass the role(manager or something else) to the annotation and do the job.

Do I have to create AccessType Enum. And based on the session set the role?  We already use Spring Security for authentication and authorization.

Any help will be appreciated !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement [spring security](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-security-webapp-spring-config.html). See the link for a place to start looking and Googling, as a full tutorial on this subject, I think, is outside the scope of this question. when you have implemented a spring security context each user will have associated roles and you can use the @RolesAllowed annotation like your example.

[Here's a blog](http://mark.koli.ch/2010/07/spring-3-and-spring-security-setting-your-own-custom-j-spring-security-check-filter-processes-url.html) to walk you through implementing your own security filter through spring.

-- In response to a comment:

Spring security can work with custom roles, as well. In the spring security context you can define an authentication provider:

```
<authentication-provider user-service-ref='daoAuthenticationProvider'>
    <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
</authentication-provider>
<beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="com.custom.DaoAuthenticationProvider"/>
```

and have that extend AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider. Here you can have custom code to serve up a UserDetails object for a specific user. The UserDetails object will have the roles that you want to use to restrict access elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks but the Roles are custom. They are not defined in SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT but somewhere in the session in another object. How can I use that session to get the roles and use it in the annotation? FYI: I am using Spring 2.5. I am walking through the tutorial but not sure if it can be done in Spring 2.5

Comment: Extended the answer. Hopefully that helps with your implementation. I know the spring security configuration can be a bit confusing at first.

Answer (score 2):

the same scenario i have explained in my blog and you can refer the blog post [available here](http://chathurangat.blogspot.com/2013/05/spring-security-form-based-login-user.html) here i have used the Spring Security AOP based authorization. with spring security AOP based authorization you can use `@Secured` annotation with role name(s) on top of method declaration to allow the access only for the define user role(s).

```
//access will be granted only the users with ROLE_MANAGER
@Secured("ROLE_MANAGER")
public ModelAndView showManagerHomePage(){

}

//access will be granted only the users with ROLE_MANAGER or ROLE_ADMIN
@Secured({"ROLE_MANAGER","ROLE_ADMIN"})
public ModelAndView showAdminUserHomePage(){

}
```